# Sublime Text - Build code with frozen importlib._bootstrap_external error

Tags: python

I installed Python 3.7 and type PRINT ("TEST") in sublime text. After pressing "Ctrl + B" to build code, below error prompted.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\py_compile.py", line 212, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\py_compile.py", line 204, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "C:\Users\barry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\py_compile.py", line 140, in compile
    source_bytes = loader.get_data(file)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
[Finished in 1.6s]
```

Answer (score 0):

`PRINT ("TEST")` is incorrect (Python is case sensitive). Have you tried `print ("TEST")`?

Comment: Yes, i tried to use small capital letter and with same error

Comment: Is it saved to a file?

Answer (score 0):

as @LeopardShark commented: You must save the file before you can compile it.